# How to plot logistic regression decision boundary?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression

I am running logistic regression on a small dataset which looks like this:

[image]

After implementing gradient descent and the cost function, I am getting a 100% accuracy in the prediction stage, However I want to be sure that everything is in order so I am trying to plot the decision boundary line which separates the two datasets.

Below I present plots showing the cost function and theta parameters. As can be seen, currently I am printing the decision boundary line incorrectly.

[image]

**Extracting data**

```
clear all; close all; clc;

alpha = 0.01;
num_iters = 1000;

%% Plotting data
x1 = linspace(0,3,50);
mqtrue = 5;
cqtrue = 30;
dat1 = mqtrue*x1+5*randn(1,50);

x2 = linspace(7,10,50);
dat2 = mqtrue*x2 + (cqtrue + 5*randn(1,50));

x = [x1 x2]'; % X

subplot(2,2,1);
dat = [dat1 dat2]'; % Y

scatter(x1, dat1); hold on;
scatter(x2, dat2, '*'); hold on;
classdata = (dat>40);
```

**Computing Cost, Gradient and plotting**

```
%  Setup the data matrix appropriately, and add ones for the intercept term
[m, n] = size(x);

% Add intercept term to x and X_test
x = [ones(m, 1) x];

% Initialize fitting parameters
theta = zeros(n + 1, 1);
%initial_theta = [0.2; 0.2];

J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1); 

plot_x = [min(x(:,2))-2,  max(x(:,2))+2]

for iter = 1:num_iters 
% Compute and display initial cost and gradient
    [cost, grad] = logistic_costFunction(theta, x, classdata);
    theta = theta - alpha * grad;
    J_history(iter) = cost;

    fprintf('Iteration #%d - Cost = %d... \r\n',iter, cost);


    subplot(2,2,2);
    hold on; grid on;
    plot(iter, J_history(iter), '.r');  title(sprintf('Plot of cost against number of iterations. Cost is %g',J_history(iter)));
    xlabel('Iterations')
    ylabel('MSE')
    drawnow

    subplot(2,2,3);
    grid on;
    plot3(theta(1), theta(2), J_history(iter),'o')
    title(sprintf('Tita0 = %g, Tita1=%g', theta(1), theta(2)))
    xlabel('Tita0')
    ylabel('Tita1')
    zlabel('Cost')
    hold on;
    drawnow

    subplot(2,2,1);
    grid on;    
    % Calculate the decision boundary line
    plot_y = theta(2).*plot_x + theta(1);  % <--- Boundary line 
    % Plot, and adjust axes for better viewing
    plot(plot_x, plot_y)
    hold on;
    drawnow

end

fprintf('Cost at initial theta (zeros): %f\n', cost);
fprintf('Gradient at initial theta (zeros): \n');
fprintf(' %f \n', grad);
```

The above code is implementing gradient descent correctly (I think) but I am still unable to show the boundary line plot. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

---

**logistic_costFunction.m**

```
function [J, grad] = logistic_costFunction(theta, X, y)

    % Initialize some useful values
    m = length(y); % number of training examples

    grad = zeros(size(theta));

    h = sigmoid(X * theta);
    J = -(1 / m) * sum( (y .* log(h)) + ((1 - y) .* log(1 - h)) );

    for i = 1 : size(theta, 1)
        grad(i) = (1 / m) * sum( (h - y) .* X(:, i) );
    end

end
```

**EDIT:**

As per the below answer by @Esmailian, now I have something like this:

```
[m, n] = size(x);

x1_class = [ones(m, 1) x1' dat1'];
x2_class = [ones(m, 1) x2' dat2'];

x = [x1_class ; x2_class]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Regarding the code

1. You should plot the decision boundary after training is finished, not inside the training loop, parameters are constantly changing there; unless you are tracking the change of decision boundary.
2. `x1` (`x2`) is the first feature and `dat1` (`dat2`) is the second feature for the first (second) class, so the extended feature space `x` for both classes should be the union of `(1, x1, dat1)` and `(1, x2, dat2)`.

#### Decision boundary

Assuming that data is $\boldsymbol{x}=(x_1, x_2)$ (`(x, dat)` or `(plot_x, plot_y)` in the code), and parameter is $\boldsymbol{\theta}=(\theta_0, \theta_1,\theta_2)$ (`(theta(1), theta(2), theta(3))` in the code), here is the line that should be drawn as decision boundary:
$$x_2 = -\frac{\theta_1}{\theta_2} x_1 - \frac{\theta_0}{\theta_2}$$
which can be drawn as a segment by connecting two points $(0, - \frac{\theta_0}{\theta_2})$ and $(- \frac{\theta_0}{\theta_1}, 0)$.
However, if $\theta_2=0$, the line would be $x_1=-\frac{\theta_0}{\theta_1}$.

#### Where this comes from?

Decision boundary of Logistic regression is the set of all points $\boldsymbol{x}$ that satisfy
$${\Bbb P}(y=1|\boldsymbol{x})={\Bbb P}(y=0|\boldsymbol{x}) = \frac{1}{2}.$$
Given
$${\Bbb P}(y=1|\boldsymbol{x})=\frac{1}{1+e^{-\boldsymbol{\theta}^t\boldsymbol{x_+}}}$$
where $\boldsymbol{\theta}=(\theta_0, \theta_1,\cdots,\theta_d)$, and $\boldsymbol{x}$ is extended to $\boldsymbol{x_+}=(1, x_1, \cdots, x_d)$ for the sake of readability to have$$\boldsymbol{\theta}^t\boldsymbol{x_+}=\theta_0 + \theta_1 x_1+\cdots+\theta_d x_d,$$
decision boundary can be derived as follows
$$\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{1+e^{-\boldsymbol{\theta}^t\boldsymbol{x_+}}} = \frac{1}{2} \\
&\Rightarrow \boldsymbol{\theta}^t\boldsymbol{x_+} = 0\\
&\Rightarrow \theta_0 + \theta_1 x_1+\cdots+\theta_d x_d = 0
\end{align*}$$
For two dimensional data $\boldsymbol{x}=(x_1, x_2)$ we have
$$\begin{align*}
& \theta_0 + \theta_1 x_1+\theta_2 x_2 = 0 \\
& \Rightarrow x_2 = -\frac{\theta_1}{\theta_2} x_1 - \frac{\theta_0}{\theta_2}
\end{align*}$$
which is the separation line that should be drawn in $(x_1, x_2)$ plane.

#### Weighted decision boundary

If we want to weight the positive class ($y = 1$) more or less using $w$, here is the general decision boundary:
$$w{\Bbb P}(y=1|\boldsymbol{x}) = {\Bbb P}(y=0|\boldsymbol{x}) = \frac{w}{w+1}$$

For example, $w=2$ means point $\boldsymbol{x}$ will be assigned to positive class if ${\Bbb P}(y=1|\boldsymbol{x}) > 0.33$ (or equivalently if ${\Bbb P}(y=0|\boldsymbol{x}) < 0.66$), which implies favoring the positive class (increasing the true positive rate).

Here is the line for this general case:
$$\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{1+e^{-\boldsymbol{\theta}^t\boldsymbol{x_+}}} = \frac{1}{w+1} \\
&\Rightarrow e^{-\boldsymbol{\theta}^t\boldsymbol{x_+}} = w\\
&\Rightarrow \boldsymbol{\theta}^t\boldsymbol{x_+} = -\text{ln}w\\
&\Rightarrow \theta_0 + \theta_1 x_1+\cdots+\theta_d x_d = -\text{ln}w
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks for your insight, I understand why I need three `thetas` and the weighted decision boundary you explain. I am still having trouble implementing this in code however. ABove you say: "Assuming that input `x=(x1, x2)` ... Isn't this what I present in the code above?

Comment: Gradient descent is implemented correctly, but I am having issue with mismatching matrix dimensions when it comes to the input X and `classdata`. Shouldn't `x ` be `nx3` ? `[x1, x2, 1`]

Comment: @Rrz0 that is the extended 3D version as I explained, which is actually X+ = [1, x, dat], you do not need this for drawing the line. Please check my last update regarding 'plot_x'.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I edited the question to show the cost function.. When computing the sigmoid we get `X * theta`. I believe this results in a dimension error if X is not [n x 3]

Comment: @Rrz0 I spotted the problem. Check out the update.

Comment: Thank you for the updates to the answer. Your second point regarding the data features helped me understand much better. I updated my question to show how I do what you suggest. I will proceed to run and try to plot.

Comment: Is a weighted decision boundary the same as a weighted cross entropy?

Answer (score 12):

Your decision boundary is a surface in 3D as your points are in 2D.

With [Wolfram Language](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/)

Create the data sets.

```
mqtrue = 5;
cqtrue = 30;
With[{x = Subdivide[0, 3, 50]},
  dat1 = Transpose@{x, mqtrue x + 5 RandomReal[1, Length@x]};
  ];
With[{x = Subdivide[7, 10, 50]},
  dat2 = Transpose@{x, mqtrue x + cqtrue + 5 RandomReal[1, Length@x]};
  ];
```

View in 2D ([`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html)) and the 3D ([`ListPointPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPointPlot3D.html)) regression space.

```
ListPlot[{dat1, dat2}, PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers", PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

I [`Append`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Append.html) the response variable to the data.

```
datPlot =
 ListPointPlot3D[
  MapThread[Append, {#, Boole@Thread[#[[All, 2]] > 40]}] & /@ {dat1, dat2}
  ]
```

> [image]

Perform a Logistic regression ([`LogitModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogitModelFit.html)). You could use [`GeneralizedLinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeneralizedLinearModelFit.html) with [`ExponentialFamily`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExponentialFamily.html) set to `"Binomial"` as well.

```
With[{dat = Join[dat1, dat2]},
 model =
  LogitModelFit[
   MapThread[Append, {dat, Boole@Thread[dat[[All, 2]] > 40]}],
   {x, y}, {x, y}]
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

From the [`FittedModel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FittedModel.html) `"Properties"` we need `"Function"`.

```
model["Properties"]
```

> {AdjustedLikelihoodRatioIndex,    DevianceTableDeviances, ParameterConfidenceIntervalTableEntries,
>   AIC,    DevianceTableEntries,   ParameterConfidenceRegion,
>   AnscombeResiduals,  DevianceTableResidualDegreesOfFreedom,  ParameterErrors,
>   BasisFunctions, DevianceTableResidualDeviances, ParameterPValues,
>   BestFit,    EfronPseudoRSquared,    ParameterTable,
>   BestFitParameters,  EstimatedDispersion,    ParameterTableEntries,
>   BIC,    FitResiduals,   ParameterZStatistics,
>   CookDistances,  Function,   PearsonChiSquare,
>   CorrelationMatrix,  HatDiagonal,    PearsonResiduals,
>   CovarianceMatrix,   LikelihoodRatioIndex,   PredictedResponse,
>   CoxSnellPseudoRSquared, LikelihoodRatioStatistic,   Properties,
>   CraggUhlerPseudoRSquared,   LikelihoodResiduals,    ResidualDeviance,
>   Data,   LinearPredictor,    ResidualDegreesOfFreedom,
>   DesignMatrix,   LogLikelihood,  Response,
>   DevianceResiduals,  NullDeviance,   StandardizedDevianceResiduals,
>   Deviances,  NullDegreesOfFreedom,   StandardizedPearsonResiduals,
>   DevianceTable,  ParameterConfidenceIntervals,   WorkingResiduals,
>   DevianceTableDegreesOfFreedom,  ParameterConfidenceIntervalTable}

```
model["Function"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Use this for prediction

```
model["Function"][8, 54]
```

> ```
> 0.0196842
> ```

and plot the decision boundary surface in 3D along with the data (`datPlot`) using [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) and [`Plot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot3D.html)

```
modelPlot =
 Show[
  datPlot,
  Plot3D[
   model["Function"][x, y],
   Evaluate[
    Sequence @@ 
     MapThread[Prepend, {MinMax /@ Transpose@Join[dat1, dat2], {x, y}}]],
   Mesh -> None,
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[.25, Green],
   PlotPoints -> 30
   ]
  ]
```

[image]

With [`ParametricPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html) and [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) you can examine decision boundary curves for values of the variables. For example, keeping `x` fixed and letting `y` vary or vice versa.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  modelPlot,
  ParametricPlot3D[
   {x, u, model["Function"][x, u]}, {u, 0, 80}, PlotStyle -> Orange],
  ParametricPlot3D[
   {u, y, model["Function"][u, y]}, {u, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Purple],
  PlotLabel -> 
   StringTemplate["model[`1`, `2`] = `3`"] @@ {x, y, model["Function"][x, y]}
  ],
 {{x, 6, Style["x", Orange, Bold]}, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{y, 40, Style["y", Purple, Bold]}, 0, 80, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

[image]

### Update

You can also plot contours of the probability in 2D.

```
plot = ListPlot[{dat1, dat2}, PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers", PlotTheme -> "Detailed"];

Manipulate[
 db = y /. First@Quiet@Solve[model["Function"][x, y] == p, y];
 Show[
  plot,
  Plot[db, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red]
  ],
 {{p, .5}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Beautiful plots. Some important notes: Logistic regression is used by OP for "classification" in 2D space, therefore "decision boundary" should be drawn in the same dimension $d$ as feature space (2D here) and it is a straight 2D line (unlike the last plot), which is also not the same as those animated lines (it must be parallel to that waterfall). However, "output of logistic regression", i.e. $(\boldsymbol{x},P(y=1|\boldsymbol{x}))$, as you have beautifully illustrated, needs $d+1$ for visualization.

Comment: @Esmailian See update.

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful insight and excellent visualizations.

Comment: That's a pretty strange-looking decision boundary, though. Normally you'd want the boundary to be perpendicular to the line connecting the clusters, I'd say. This is a great way to spot fitting artefacts like that.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit The red line in the last plot is a contour of the green "decision" surface. It is a line along the ramp that joins values zero and one on the z-axis.

Answer (score 0):

I have generally found that to be quite easy to do in Python without having to solve the boundary equation. (Code mostly adapted from [that question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294241/plotting-a-decision-boundary-separating-2-classes-using-matplotlibs-pyplot/22356551#22356551))

Import packages :

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
```

Generate data :

```
mu_vec1 = np.array([0,10])
cov_mat1 = np.array([[10,8],[8,10]])
x1_samples = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu_vec1, cov_mat1, 100)
mu_vec1 = mu_vec1.reshape(1,2).T # to 1-col vector

mu_vec2 = np.array([10,70])
cov_mat2 = np.array([[10,8],[8,10]])
x2_samples = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu_vec2, cov_mat2, 100)
mu_vec2 = mu_vec2.reshape(1,2).T
```

Plot generated data and save the associated figure :

```
fig = plt.figure()
    
plt.scatter(x1_samples[:,0],x1_samples[:,1], c= 'blue', marker='o')
plt.scatter(x2_samples[:,0],x2_samples[:,1], c= 'orange', marker='o')

plt.savefig('data_sample.png')
```

[image: simulated data]

Fit the logistic regression :

```
X = np.concatenate((x1_samples,x2_samples), axis = 0)
y = np.array([0]*100 + [1]*100)

model_logistic = LogisticRegression()
model_logistic.fit(X, y)
```

Create a mesh, predict the regression on that mesh, plot the associated contour along simulated data and save the plot :

```
h = .02  # step size in the mesh
x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
                     np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))

Z = model_logistic.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

fig = plt.figure()
    
plt.scatter(x1_samples[:,0],x1_samples[:,1], c= 'blue', marker='o')
plt.scatter(x2_samples[:,0],x2_samples[:,1], c= 'orange', marker='o')

Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
plt.contour(xx, yy, Z, 1, colors='black')

plt.savefig('data_contour.png')
```

[image: data + decision boundary]

This generally works for more complex dependencies (non linearities in variables) or more complex models (svm as per linked SO answer).